# Angular: Error on injecting a filter in a service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-filters

```
export class AlertsService implements IAlertsService {    

    public static $inject = ['$filter'];

    constructor(public $filter: Filters.IHtmlEncodeV2Filter) { 
    }

    public alert(alert: any, type?: string, name: string = "default", callback: any = null, callbackText: string = "default") {
        var test = this.$filter("htmlEncodeV2")(alert);
        var newAlert = new Alert(alert, type, callback, callbackText),
            alerts = this.getNamedAlerts(name);

        while (alerts.length >= this.alertLimit) {
            alerts.splice(0, 1);
        }

        alerts.push(newAlert);
    }
}
```

The above code injects the custom filter `HtmlEncodeV2` but whenever I run this, I always encounter the error `this.$filter is not a function`. Did I miss something? I've followed the convention on injecting objects on a modular way.

Comment: You didn't assign $filter to this.$filter in the constructor. Try `this.$filter = $filter` in constructor`

Comment: Turns out I just did not inject it to the module itself. Thanks for answering this btw.